# Embedding a matrix inside a subsection tag

Tags: matrices, sections-paragraphs

I recently encountered a problem where the computer displays the following errors

```
Argument of \@sect has an extra }. [}}]
Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
```

when I ask it to run the following code

```
\subsection{{\setstretch{1.2}Show that $e^D = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{d_1} & 0       & \ldots & 0     \\
0       & e^{d_2} & \ldots & 0     \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
0       & 0       & \ldots & e^{d_n} 
\end{bmatrix}$
}}
```

What is wrong? I have the brackets matched, so why isn't it happy?

Comment: there are lots of fragile commands there that would need `\protect` but that is a very weird title for a section, what is the body of the section?

Comment: A proof of the thing in the title.

Comment: If you don't need this in the table of contents or heading use `\subsection[simple title]{weird stuff}` otherwise (at least) \setstretch, \begin \end  are fragile and need \protect in a moving argument

Comment: I suspect `\setstretch{1.2}` here should be something like `\renewcommand{arraystretch}{1.2}`. I don't know if it is fragile, though.